# In Chrome, can I block the videos & images in the Google search results?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, adblock

When I do a Google search, I want to block seeing image and videos in my results.  I figured out how to block it using Adblock in Firefox, but the same rule doesn't work in Chrome.  Maybe not surprising, since the results are on Google Youtube and Images.  Has anyone found a rule that works in Chrome?  Or a different extension?  Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

There is a extension named "Block image". I think it will help you.

Comment: Unfortunately this blocks all images on all pages.